# Can't list the current job flow in Elastic map reduce Command line Tools?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

I have installed the Amazon Elastic Map Reduce Command Line Tools successfully.

While listing the current job flow, by using the below command

```
$ ./elastic-mapreduce --list
```

It throws the following Error.

```
Error: Request has expired. Timestamp date: 2013-07-09T02:48:00-07:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the time stamp (i.e) both the master node time, machine time should be equal. then only you will get the proper response.

You can check the time stamp of your master node instance through putty.

Comment: Thanks for your response @sasi i'll check whether Its working or not